# Remove the key-value pairs (nested at any level) from a Json String using LinkedTreeMap

Tags: java, gson, treemap

I have a `Json String` representing a object which further has another nested objects. Also, I have a list of keys which I need to remove from this `Json String`. These keys can be at any nested level of object inside this string. Finally I need to compare this edited Json string to another string and output the differences. I need to remove those key-value pairs from first Json string because I need to ignore those keys during comparison. Currently, I am converting the Json String to `LinkedTreeMap` provided by `Gson API` and then doing `Map.difference()` to compare. Please suggest a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by traversing recursively inside the Nested LinkedTreeMap till I find the field and remove it if it exists. The full path of `Key` needs to be provide to get the exact key-value location inside the Object (like **"objects.desc"** in the below Json Sample to remove **desc** from the Json String)

Json Sample:

```
{
    "message": "MSG",
    "code": "COD001",
    "objects": [
        {
            "resource": "Student",
            "field": "StudentId",
            "desc": "Student Description"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code Sample:

```
public MapDifference<String, Object> getMapDifference(String jsonString1, String jsonString2) {
    MapDifference<String, Object> mapDifference = null;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {
    }.getType();
    Map<String, Object> firstMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString1, mapType);
    Map<String, Object> secondMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString2, mapType);
    firstMap = CollectionUtils.isEmpty(firstMap) ? new HashMap<>() : firstMap;
    secondMap = CollectionUtils.isEmpty(secondMap) ? new HashMap<>() : secondMap;
    //This contains the List of keys that is required to be filtered out from Json Strings before comparision like {"message", "objects.desc"}
    List<String> firstIgnoreList = getIgnoreList1();
    List<String> secondIgnoreList = getIgnoreList2();

    filterKeys(firstMap, firstIgnoreList);
    filterKeys(secondMap, secondIgnoreList);

    mapDifference = Maps.difference(firstMap, secondMap);
    return mapDifference;
  }


private void filterKeys(Map<String, Object> keyMap, List<String> ignoreList) {
    if (!(CollectionUtils.isEmpty(keyMap) || CollectionUtils.isEmpty(ignoreList))) {
        ignoreList.stream().parallel().forEach(key -> recursiveRemove(keyMap, key));
    }
  }

private static void recursiveRemove(Map<String, Object> keyMap, String key) {
    List<String> path = Arrays.asList(StringUtils.split(key.trim(), "."));
    int size = path.size();
    int index = 0;
    List<LinkedTreeMap> treeMapList = new ArrayList<LinkedTreeMap>();
    treeMapList.add((LinkedTreeMap) keyMap);
    while (index != size - 1) {
      int i = index++;
      List<LinkedTreeMap> treeMapListTemp = new ArrayList<LinkedTreeMap>();
      treeMapList.stream().parallel().forEach(treeMap -> {
        Object obj = treeMap.get(path.get(i));
        if (obj instanceof List) {
          treeMapListTemp.addAll((List<LinkedTreeMap>) obj);
        } else if (obj instanceof LinkedTreeMap) {
          treeMapListTemp.add((LinkedTreeMap) obj);
        }
      });
      treeMapList = treeMapListTemp;
    }
    treeMapList.stream().parallel().forEach(treeMap -> treeMap.remove(path.get(size - 1)));
  }
```